# Haml link_to imbrication

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, link-to

Still quite new to rails environment, I am trying to render a link into an other one
I would like to reproduce the **list-group-custom-content** component

Here is the haml content this is well rendered

```
%div{:class => ["list-group"]}
    - @tickets.each do |ticket|
        = link_to "#", :class => "list-group-item" do
            %div.row
                %div{:class => "col-sm-8"}
                    %h4{:class => "list-group-item-heading"}
                        Blabla
                    %p{:class => "list-group-item-text"}
                        blabla bla blabla
                %div{:class => "col-sm-4"}
                    other content
```

[The corresponding rendered html](http://files.kitesize.com/do/d8e4e4a858be4ff73d18e8413340a5f810ec1635)

Here is the haml content that is going to fail

```
%div{:class => ["list-group"]}
    - @tickets.each do |ticket|
        = link_to "#", :class => "list-group-item" do
            %div.row
                %div{:class => "col-sm-8"}
                    %h4{:class => "list-group-item-heading"}
                        = link_to ticket.subject, "#"        -# <- Here is the problem
                    %p{:class => "list-group-item-text"}
                        blabla bla blabla
                %div{:class => "col-sm-4"}
                    other content
```

[The corresponding rendered html](http://files.kitesize.com/do/691578d9b4a71ca275d0c2f3b1462b6aa57ee399)

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Can you include the HTML that you get and what you expect to get in the actual question please? You’ll get a better response if people don’t have to go and download files from other sites.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem does not come from my haml template.
Here is the rendered html

```
<div class='list-group'>
    <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-8'>
                left
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <p class='pull-right'>
                    <a href="#">Close</a> <!-- This link cause problem -->
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-8'>
                left
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <p class='pull-right'>
                    <a href="#">Close</a> <!-- This link cause problem -->
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

As soon as I insert the link marked as causing problem the layout is completly broken
If I replace the link by

```
<button>Close</button>
```

It works
Is it a bootstrap problem or something that is not suported ?

Should I close this question and open a new one ?